# PHP-CLI + File Permissions

Tags: file-permissions, php

When you run a php script in the command line, does is execute with the read/write permissions of the current user or what?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more details about what OS you are running on.

Comment: I'm running linux, but I was wanting to know for windows as well since the script I'm working on will be running on a windows server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it runs with the permissions of the current user. Just like executing any other command-line program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will run as the current user in a default setup.

If you where on a unix system you could change this by adjusting the setuid bit of the php cli binary.  Of course doing so would be a bad idea.